# How to find duplicate and update column value of all but the most recent entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `items` with columns `item_id`, `lockup_id`, `date`, `archive`. I need to be able to go through the `lookup_id` column and identify duplicates, changing the `archive` value to 1 on every duplicate EXCEPT the newest entry in the table.

```
item_id       Lookup_id      date     archive
------------------------------------------------
1234            4           1-1-19       0
1235            4           1-1-19       0
1236            4           1-1-19       0
1237            2           1-1-19       0
1238            1           1-1-19       0
1239            1           1-1-19       0
```

I've so far managed to find the duplicates using the following statement, but I'm at a bit of a loss where to go with this to achieve my desired result.

```
'SELECT  `item_id` ,  `lookup_id`, `date`, `archive`
 FROM  items 
 WHERE  `item_id` 
 IN (
    `SELECT  `item_id` 
     FROM  items
     GROUP BY  `item_id` 
     HAVING COUNT(  `item_id` ) >1
)
ORDER BY  `item_id`;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you *need* the duplicates in the database?

Comment: Hi Jane, yeah the item_id relates to a certificate and we need to keep track of those previously issued.

Comment: How are the duplicate columns added to your db?

Comment: I ask this because I think a trigger is probably the best solution

Comment: How do you identify the "newest" entry?

Comment: I've actually inherited this table from a previous developer where archiving the items was not considered. We have over 20,000 entries now with multiple duplicates for each lookup_id. All new entries from this point will be handled before being inserted into the table, it's just the data thats already in place that is our problem.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Using the item_id, its an autoincrement

Comment: I don't see you using `lookup_id` in your query to identify duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two steps.

First set all values in `archive` to `1`:

```
update items set archive = 1 where 1;
```

Then set `archive = 0` for "newest" entries only:

```
update items i
inner join (
  select max(item_id) as item_id
  from items
  group by Lookup_id
) x using(item_id)
set i.archive = 0;
```

You will get the following result:

```
item_id     Lookup_id   date    archive
   1234             4   1-1-19        1
   1235             4   1-1-19        1
   1236             4   1-1-19        0
   1237             2   1-1-19        0
   1238             1   1-1-19        1
   1239             1   1-1-19        0
```

This method should be quite efficient with an index on `(Lookup_id, item_id)`.

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9U2aC71GCYSpant3xwg3Sc/0)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you example I am assuming the latest entry is the one with highest item  id

if that's  the case you can create a CTE with a column and use row number / partition by

Something like this - the join will change depending on which columns are unique

```
 ;WITH cte_test  AS
 (SELECT item_id , lookup_id , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lookup_id  ORDER BY item_id ) AS rn 
 FROM items ) 
 UPDATE it2
  SET it2.archive = 1
  FROM items it2
  INNER JOIN cte_test ct 
  ON ct.item_id = it2.item_id
  AND ct.lookup_id = it2.lookup_id where rn > 1
```

Comment: Hi Paul - yes it will work - though I realized that I forgot to add the condition rn > 1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `item_id` is sequential, assuming newest entry has the highest `item_id` you could filter for the highest `item_id` for each `lookup_id` and then update all records except these.

```sql
update items set archive = 1
where item_id not in 
  (
    select max(item_id) from items 
    group by lookup_id
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to archive all the items with the same lookup_id except the newer one you can use this sql statement

```
UPDATE tn SET tn.archive = 1 
FROM table_name tn
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(tn2.id) FROM table_name AS tn2 WHERE tn2.lookup_id = tn.lookup_id) > 1 
AND tn.id NOT IN (SELECT tn2.id FROM table_name AS tn2 WHERE tn2.lookup_id = tn.lookup_id ORDER BY tn.date DESC, tn.id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

In the where conditions first we check if more than one item with the same lookup_id exists and then we check that the actual item is not the newer of all the items with the same lookup_id.